# Why was my answer flagged as missing sources?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question

https://askubuntu.com/a/1371070/448998

The Community bot flagged this answer for missing sources:

> Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Why did this happen?

I cited multiple pieces of documentation: freedesktop.org and two man pages; I also cited a Unix.SE answer. Only once did I cite my experience with Apache.

Was I supposed to also

> quote

the documentation?

The answer is already long enough and I thought that just summarizing most important points would be sufficient. Also, I once quoted the default contents of a configuration file, since these were hard to link to. Was I incorrect?

How do I improve this answer so that it is no longer missing "*additional supporting information*"?

Comment: So this is weird but the community user didn't leave that comment a reviewer did from the first answers queue, share feedback option. This means it wasn't some sort of automatic message and that user would have to come and explain what they mean here, I don't know what they mean or why they chose to post with community (no comment replys?, seems to defeat the point of leaving feedback IMO). Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369272/resolving-community-user-and-share-feedback-issues-in-review-queues

Comment: FYI while one user decided to leave feedback, two others have okayed it and it has passed review, you don't need to worry about the answer deleted or anything like that. See your posts timeline here: https://askubuntu.com/posts/1371070/timeline

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So... my honest opinion... this new feature of review where people can leave canned "feedback" as Community♦ is *the worst feature ever*. It encourages reviewers to treat the task as something completely meaningless and throwaway. There is no accountability - one can't straightforwardly tell who decided to leave the comment (it's possible by [digging around](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369073/322419)), or reply to it.

While I have once or twice seen these comments saying something relevant to the post they were on, the vast majority of them make little to no sense where posted. I have been deleting all of them. I'm sorry this one didn't get deleted before it caused you confusion. Thankfully jokerdino♦ has removed it.

Comment: "one can't tell who decided to leave the comment" You may know this but for those who don't, you can still find who left the comment (you still can't tag them in comments though as far as I know) by going to the timeline and just clicking on the review task that says community left a comment, it will take you to the actual review and show you who made it. This could be an oversight but it works. I guess you need 3k rep to see this.

Comment: @MarkKirby [yeah](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369073/322419) - the timeline and review items are viewable to all as long as the post isn't deleted, I think. And yeah, you can't tag the person who left the comment in a reply. I think I'll just edit my answer to mention this...