# Out of context comments from the community bot

Tags: discussion

[This](https://askubuntu.com/q/1374518/124466) question is quite clearly written, and has not been edited so far.

There was a comment from the [Community Bot](https://askubuntu.com/users/-1/community) (which I flagged):

> Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Since the OP described the problem quite clearly, *"it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking"* clearly does not apply here.

Do these comments automatically appear to the questions of every new user? They are not helping very much.

Comment: These aren't bots. The review queues allow people to leave comments as community for some reason. If you look at the timeline you can see first post review was completed and the reviewer chose to share feedback https://askubuntu.com/review/first-questions/1182846 Also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369272/resolving-community-user-and-share-feedback-issues-in-review-queues and https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19782/why-was-my-answer-flagged-as-missing-sources It is very confusing and deletes the point of leaving review feedback IMO.

Comment: I've just deleted all of Community♦'s comments again. I'm thinking of writing a meta post asking people to please not use this horrible feature at all

Comment: @Zanna Why are you still thinking , Write it right now !

Comment: Let's allow even mods to have a second life every now and then.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374847/my-ubuntu-dark-theme-does-not-work-properly-how-can-i-make-it-back-to-normal#comment2366505_1374847 Again

Comment: @Zanna the SE team is staunchly for that feature, so bring it up on the Teacher's Lounge or uber meta. Otherwise, you will be against the tide.

Comment: Why would I want to bring it up there? Our community doesn't like it. The rest of the network can do what they like. I have subzero interest in arguing with people outside of the Ask Ubuntu community about this. Picking battles.

Comment: I have no idea of mods can do this... but as an alternative to just saying "Don't review anonymously", can mods change the message it automatically says to be something a bit more useful?

Comment: @cocomac mods have no control over those canned comments, but in any case my problem is less with the uselessness of the canned comments than with the way this feature turns review into a(n even more) throwaway task and removes reviewer accountability

Comment: (anyway w/r/t/ bringing this up elsewhere I know plenty of mods across the network hate this feature as much as me)